# ANOVA ASSUMPTIONS, LOW or NONE VARIANCE IN PART OF DATA

Tags: boxplot

It was said to me there is a problem here, cause there is no variance of the control and ulex treatment - it can be the nature of the data or it can be the assumptions to apply anova in these data were not achieved.

[[image: Graph built with RAW DATA look the variance in first and second boxplots]]

The data was log transformed and I think it looks ok in the diagnosis graphs, but maybe I'm not experienced enough to interpret the diagnosis graphs, so I'm asking for your help on this. Graphs are below.
[[image: Diagnosis over log transformed data - qqplot]]
[[image: Diagnosis over log transformed data]]

You maybe interested in look at the Phosphorus raw data to tell me the variance is related to the nature of the data, but what can I say about it so?

```
4  Control Woodland
```

```
5  Control Woodland
```

```
4  Control Woodland
```

```
4  Control Woodland
```

```
3  Control Woodland
```

```
8  U. europaeus    Woodland
```

```
4  U. europaeus    Woodland
```

```
4  U. europaeus    Woodland
```

```
4  U. europaeus    Woodland
```

```
4  U. europaeus    Woodland
```